# How to replace custom token that is in RichText field using Sitecore JSS?

Tags: jss, pipelines

I have a custom token `%tokenname%` in `single line text` and `richtext` fields. I would like to replace the token with some custom value in the Sitecore `JSON rendering`. Please see some example data below:

```
{
  "uid": "04f1b740-1eff-415e-a1c3-93bce2c2a274",
  "componentName": "GeneralContent",
  "dataSource": "{0F766E67-7341-4155-B53F-5BEA598C8C24}",  
  "fields": {
    "Subheading": {
      "value": "" 
    },
    "Body": {
      "value": "This is the %tokenname% I would like to buy"
    },
    "Heading": {
      "value": "Limited to number of %tokenname% to buy."
    }
  }
}
```

Just wondering where can I do that. I tried with `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField` pipeline which doesn't work. Is that because I can't use it for `JSON Rendering` which is different from the traditional Sitecore `MVC Controller Rendering`?

Comment: Can we have some front end code where you are consuming the field?  You should be able to manipulate the value before displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in Sitecore JSS case, fields are not being processed by the `RenderField` pipeline, therefore, you have to implement your custom token replacement yourself while rendering the concerned fields.